# How do I listen for Events starting at a previous block number in Golang?

Tags: go-ethereum, events, golang

I'm writing an Event listener for my smart contract using the `go-ethereum` library. I'm trying to figure out how to listen for all `SubmitProof` events and have successfully been able to use the builtin contract methods to start listening at the latest block. Here's my code for that:

```go
package ethereum

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "sync"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"

    "github.com/my-proj/contracts"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    contract, err := contracts.NewOracle(common.HexToAddress("0xafB0d8E313Fb2018098334F2B53435382BEaD561"), client)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(1)
    go listenForSubmitProof(ctx, &wg, contract)

    wg.Wait()
}

func listenForSubmitProof(ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup, contract *contracts.Oracle) {
    defer wg.Done()

    events := make(chan *contracts.OracleSubmitProof)

    var start uint64 = 10472304
    opts := &bind.WatchOpts{
        Start:   &start,
        Context: ctx,
    }

    subscription, err := contract.WatchSubmitProof(opts, events, nil, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer subscription.Unsubscribe()

    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("done")
        case err := <-subscription.Err():
            fmt.Println(err)
        case event := <-events:
            blockNumber, err := client.BlockNumber(ctx)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }

            fmt.Printf("event happened at block %v", blockNumber)
            fmt.Printf("event: %v\n", event)
        }
    }
}
```

However, this only starts listening for events at the latest block onward. What I would expect is for the `bind.WatchOpts` to take the `Start` option and start scanning for events from *that* block forward.

```go
    var start uint64 = 10472304
    opts := &bind.WatchOpts{
        Start:   &start,
        Context: ctx,
    }
```

I'm not entirely sure what the `Start` option is supposed to do, but I don't think I can use it to accomplish my goal.

Is there an easy way to start listening for events starting at block X? Or do I need to do an [Event read](https://goethereumbook.org/event-read/) first and then start listening at the latest block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try using FilterOpts if you want to get historical data, if you want both historical and live events you should combine both.